# Guardar cambio de valor de variable css con localstorage

Tags: javascript, css, html5, local-storage

estoy practicando en una pagina en la cual se puede cambiar el color de esta en cuatro colores con sus respectivos botones.

```
 <div class="Colores">
    <button class="BtnTema" data-bg="#48b10b"></button>
    <button class="BtnTema" data-bg="#004369"></button>
    <button class="BtnTema" data-bg="#000"></button>
    <button class="BtnTema" data-bg="#350183"></button>
 </div>
```

Tengo el siguiente código en JavaScript el cual realiza el cambio del valor de la variable css

```
let root = document.querySelector(":root");

BtnColores.forEach(color=>{

    color.addEventListener("click", () =>{

        let dataColor = color.getAttribute("data-bg");

        root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", dataColor);

    })  
 })
```

Lo anterior funciona correctamente, lo que pasa es que quiero guardar el color elegido por el usuario con localstorage.

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero no guarda el valor.

```
localStorage.setItem("color", dataColor);
if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "#48b10b"){ //valor por defecto
   root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#004369");
   console.log("color verde: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

}else if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "#004369"){
   root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#004369");
   console.log("color azul: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

}else if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "#000"){
    root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#000");
    console.log("color negro: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

}else if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "#350183"){
     root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#350183");
     console.log("color morado: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));
}
```

Comment: El código que muestras no guarda el color porque ni siquiera lo intenta, ya que lo que hace es _recuperar_ el color que esté almacenado.

Comment: En tu código no está el elemento llamado "color".

Comment: ¿De dónde sale BtnColores? La consola la coloca como no definida. Sería bueno mostrar todas las líneas de código que intervengan en tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes guardar el color cuando el usuario lo selecciona al hacer clic en el botón correspondiente:

```
let root = document.querySelector(":root");

BtnColores.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let dataColor = color.getAttribute("data-bg");
        root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", dataColor);
        // Guardar color en localStorage cuando se selecciona
        localStorage.setItem("color", dataColor);
    })  
});
```

Al cargar la página, lees el color seleccionado, en caso de que no exista en localStorage, asignas el valor por defecto y analizas para aplicarlo:

```
// Leer color y almacenarlo en una variable
// Si no existe, asignar valor por defecto
let color = localStorage.getItem("color") || '#48b10b';

// Ahora usa esa variable para analizar
if(color == "#48b10b") { //valor por defecto
   root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#004369");
   console.log("color verde: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

} else if(color == "#004369") {
   root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#004369");
   console.log("color azul: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

} else if(color == "#000") {
    root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#000");
    console.log("color negro: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));

} else if(color == "#350183") {
     root.style.setProperty("--mainColor", "#350183");
     console.log("color morado: " + root.style.getPropertyValue("--mainColor"));
}
```

Aunque lo ideal sería que tengas este último código dentro de una función por si necesitas aplicar los cambios de color tanto en la carga inicial como en un evento.